# Не работает background-image в Chrome и Opera

Tags: google-chrome, opera, javascript, windows-8, css

См.: http://jsbin.com/EnAYeGIY/1

в качестве фона установлено

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/800x800");
}
```

Должен быть серый фон с цифрами 800.
В Фаерфоксе все ОК. Однако в Хроме (32.0.1700.76 m) есть странный глюк: если развернуть окно в полный размер экрана то фон пропадает (отображается просто чёрный фон). Если немного уменьшить (до ширины 1780px (откуда эта цифра взялась ума не приложу)) то фон появляется.

Проблема сохраняется в Опере (http://img.by/i/VkteZ.png - принтскрин не мой, другого пользователя).

Пробовал отключать все расширения браузера, использовать режим инкогнито, удалять кеш и куки - ни чего не помогает. У многих (вроде) работает корректно, что ещё более усложняет понимание причин проблемы. Сижу под Win 8.1.

Помогите пожалуйста, коллеги!

Comment: @Vega, странно-странно, у меня ваша ссылка нормально работает. Отличный фон!

Comment: У меня тоже все ок. Хром и Опера последних версий.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в position: absolute в классе .os-phrases h2. Судя по описанию, проблема эта только в webkit браузерах, баг

Answer (score 0):

именно тот кусок, что представили вы, работает как надо. ищите проблему в обработчиках изменения размеров окна, если у вас есть таковые в коде.

Comment: Таковых в коде нет.